# Applying a function in a criterion in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have in column `A` a list of integers and I want to sum them in `B1`. Then I can simply write `=SUM(A:A)`. Suppose I want the sum of integers less than 10, then I can write `SUMIF(A:A,"<=10")`. What if I now want to sum the integers which are **perfect squares**?

I could always make a column `C` with in first cell (`C1`) `=INT(SQRT(A1))=SQRT(A1)`, then `=INT(SQRT(A2))=SQRT(A2)` and so on. Then I can probably write in `B1`, something like `SUMIF(C:C,"TRUE",A:A)`, and then proceed to hide the ugly column `C`.

But isn't there a simpler and neater way to do this? I couldn't seem to find a way to apply a function in a criterion. If for example `@x` were a **placeholder name** (a variable) for the value on which the criterion is applied on, I could write `"@x<=10"` for `"<=10"`, but more usefully, I could write `"INT(SQRT(@x))=SQRT(@x)"` directly instead of making a `C` column as before. My question is then,

> Is there a simple way to create such useful criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a helper column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A)*(INT(SQRT(A:A))^2=A:A))
```

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. This does not require an array formula since `SUMPRODUCT` makes the array internally.
2. To be more efficient, the range should be limited to the actual cells containing data; like: `A1:A99`

Comment: Aaargh! four seconds too slow! :)

Comment: Nice, I think all answers do the job, though this one necessitates no array formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special kind of formulas being entered via Ctrl+Shift+Enter

They are called Array Formulas and look in figure parenthesis (added by Excel):

```
{ =SUM( IF( INT(SQRT(A1:A100))=SQRT(A1:A100); A1:A100; 0 ) ) }
```

As you can see, these formulas allow to calculate any custom expressions and sum any other expressions, e.g.:

```
{ =SUM( IF( INT(SQRT(A1:A100))=SQRT(A1:A100); B1:B100; C101:C200 ) ) }
```

Small notice: as I remember (I used these formulas many many years ago) they couldn't work with intervals of kind **A:A** so I had to use **A1:A16384** to use the whole column

Currently I can't check (because of Linux and Libre Office under the hand) but probably Microsoft has improved this point and allowed to use simple unlimited intervals like **A:A**

Official manual: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Additionally: https://www.vertex42.com/blog/excel-formulas/array-formula-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

If one has the new Dynamic Array Formulas we can use Filter and Stealing @Gary'sStudents check:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A,INT(SQRT(A:A))^2=A:A))
```

[image]